# Can only export lists but no site template with PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I want to transfer a small SharePoint Site to a different tenant with PnP.

I log in with the following command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite -UseWebLogin
```

When exporting the site template, I get an error when I include (don't exclude) lists.

```
Get-PnpSiteTemplate -Out TemplateExport.xml
>> Get-PnPSiteTemplate : GetAccessTokenAsync() called without an ACS token generator. 
   Specify in AuthenticationManager constructor the authentication parameters
```

If I exclude lists, the export works fine (no error).

```
Get-PnpSiteTemplate -Out TemplateExport.xml -excludeHandlers Lists
```

If I export only lists by themselves, I don't get an error either.

```
Export-PnPListToSiteTemplate -List "MyList" -Out ListTemplateExport.xml
```

Why does the list template export work by itself, but the site template export fails with the lists?

Can I find out which part of the list export fails?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to disable MFA for a user and connect without the "-UseWebLogin" flag.

Then Get-PnPSiteTemplate command worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following PowerShell commands:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get the Context & Web Objects
$ClientContext = Get-PnPContext
$Web = Get-PnPWeb
 
#Get All Web Templates
$WebTemplateCollection = $Web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033,0)
$ClientContext.Load($WebTemplateCollection)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
 
#Get the Template Name and Title
$WebTemplateCollection | Select Name, Title
```

For Reference: [Get Site Templates in SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/get-site-template-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)